# Deploying a Full Stack Node app npm / package.json architecture

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, npm

I have [a repository](https://github.com/gkatsanos/isawyou/) which contains a backend (Node/Express) and a Frontend client, as such:

```
├── build
├── config
├── coverage
│   └── lcov-report
├── dist
│   └── static
├── server (node/express server)
│   ├── coverage
│   ├── docs
|   ├── src
│   ├── etc
│   └── package.json
|
├── src (Vue.js : client code)
│   ├── api
│   ├── assets
│   ├── components
│   ├── router
│   └── store
└── static
└── package.json
```

I have two package.json files, one for the client and one for the server.

1. I face issues deploying on services such as Heroku as they don't expect two different npm packages in one repository (I think). How is it possible to deploy to Heroku (or others) with this setup?
2. Would it be wiser to have 1 package.json file for both parts of the application?

Which would be the advantage and disadvantages of having both frontend and backend parts in the same package.json?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [heroku-postbuild](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process) and maintain separate package.json files for your client and server in a single git repo that you push to Heroku.

For example, in one of my projects, the directory structure looks like this:

```
|-- package.json (for node/express server)
|-- Procfile
|-- www
    |--client
       |-- package.json (for Ionic/Angular client app)
       |-- ...
    |--server
       |--- ...
    |-- server.js (top level node.js/express script for server)
```

In my top-level package.json, I have:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node www/server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd www/client && npm install && npm run build"
 },
```

In my client package.json I have:

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    ...
 },
```

And finally in my Procfile I have:

```
web: npm start
```

With this solution, Heroku runs my server and builds my client code on every Heroku build.

I think client and server package.jsons should be kept separate for several reasons. For one thing, you really don't want all your server-side code bundled into your client.

Comment: What I don't like about this solution is that I can't really have two sibling client/server directories as Heroku (or anyother service) will by default look for a root package.json file.. you can't tell it where to start from (I guess you can but I dont know how)

Comment: I think you may need to fiddle around with Heroku's node buildpack in order to achieve that. See some discussion about that at https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/issues/385.

Comment: This repo shows the setup of Node.js serving up a React frontend running on a single Heroku dyno: https://github.com/mars/heroku-cra-node I was able to get one up and running using this as a guide. For cleanliness i modified my folder structure to be very similar to above: / , client/ , server/ , each with their own package.json. I think for smaller apps this is the way to go since you pay for 1 dyno instead of 2, and as the app grows it would be easy to split them out as separate apps.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem deploying to heroku.
I use a package called concurrently to start client side and server side via just the start script in the server side package.json. I also use node's built in proxy feature to send any requests from the client to the server by adding a line to the client package.json.

By the way, I use create-react-app for the client side so thats why some stuff looks a little strange.

My folder structure is

```
Server folder
   Server package.json
   Client folder
      Client package.json
```

Server package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
  "server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
  "server-dev": "nodemon --watch ./ --exec babel-node -- server.js",
  "client": "node start-client.js",
  "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server-dev\" \"npm run client\"",
  "lint": "eslint ."
 },
```

Client package.json:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
```

I assume Heroku just looks for a start script and runs that.
I think having some degree of separation between your server and client is a good idea so I wouldn't recommend trying to fit it all in one package.json

If you want you could probably find a tutorial online by googling with keywords like: heroku concurrently server client

btw, you don't need CORS if you set up like this

Cheers

Comment: hey :) I upvoted your answer: I tried before to do it like that but I had issues (with Azure which is a ****) I think it will work. The only issue is the client folder needs to be nested in the server which I dont like very much. Would there be a way to tell Heroku to start from a specific package.json regardless if its on the root level or not?

Comment: Hey, yeah i think you can use a Procfile instead which heroku will look at first. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar issues. I have found that the easiest solution is to have two separate Git repositories, one for the backend and one for the frontend. Then there is only one package.json in the root folder of each repository.

You could then create a third repository and use Git submodules to include the backend and frontend repositories. You would use the "combined" repository to do development work, but you would deploy the individual repositories. This offers the most compatibility with deployment tools while allowing you to still maintain a single repository for easy development.

Comment: "deploying individual repositories" means I would need two separate instances for example? this is the core of my issue.
Do you have an example project like that?

Comment: I would consider not using an instance for a Vue.js app at all. I use Ember.js (like Vue.js) and Sails.js (like Express) for most projects. I would do an instance (actually multiple in a autoscaling group with a load balancer) for the Sails.js app. I would then deploy Ember.js to a CDN like CloudFront. Using a CDN for static assets is way cheaper and offers much lower latency for clients.

Comment: just to clarify I am just experimenting with free tier services and deployments although trying to keep it realistic and prematurely optimizing :)

Comment: AWS CloudFront is a great option for that! https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/

Comment: but then the API would have to "live" also in AWS for latency issues etc etc? (and I would have to enable CORS headers or setup a proxy)

Comment: You could definitely leave your API in Heroku or any other service. Browsers download the client code and then run it which calls the API. Your goal should be to get both as close to the client as possible. Setting up a proxy would defeat the purpose of a CDN. You would have to setup CORS headers.

Comment: do you have an example project using the submodule pattern and a client / server split ? would I need also a combined/root repo package.json?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158275/discussion-between-alec-fenichel-and-george-katsanos).

Comment: Would you make a single shell script to make both repository deployments at the same time?