# Deploying Vue.js application consuming REST API

Tags: rest, heroku, deployment, vuejs2, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my first Vue.js application on Heroku, but I need some clarification.

My app is a very simple client consuming REST service API.

I deployed the REST service on a Heroku dyno and now I need to also deploy my front-end application.

Is it possible to install client app on the same dyno? Is it a good practice, or should I deploy the client as a separate application?
What is the "real-world" production approach?

**NOTE** REST APIs are based on Java/Spring MVC.

Comment: Are you using Maven?. If so, I can give you an example of how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible, and can keep your dyno costs down.
I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47124869/deploying-a-full-stack-node-app-npm-package-json-architecture/47132360#47132360). That specific answer may or may not be suitable to your needs depending on what server technology you are using etc., however, the general idea is that you can certainly maintain multiple parts of your app within a single git repo that gets deployed to a single Heroku app.

Such a single Heroku app may or may not consist of multiple [Process Types](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#process-types-as-templates) which may each run on one or more dynos.